# JavaScript convert namedNodeMap to string

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I'm in a process of building a debug tool for myself and what I need to do is to convert a `namedNodeMap` to text or a value which i can display using `alert()`, `innerHTML` or a `console.log()`. Basically a string. But is there an actual way to do this?
Here is my code which returns a `namedNodeMap` of any clicked element:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
    text = target.attributes

  console.log(text);

}, false);
```

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='some_class' id="some_id"></div>
<div class='some_class' data-attribute="some_data"></div>
```

For this data to be displayed as plain text it needs to be converted but how? And what would be the best way?

Comment: `Array.from` to turn into an array?

Comment: Yeah i didnt think about that... let me edit the question.. What i need is plain text.

Comment: What do you want it to be? Please add a sample output? You can convert it to an array pretty easily: `text = [...target.attributes]`

Comment: Well... I want it to be displayed as an alert or a console log. Your way will convert it to an object.

Comment: So you just want to see the data in a `console.log()`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't know why didn't this comment show up 12 hours ago.

Answer (score 3):

Each attribute in the map has [several properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr#Properties). Probably the most interesting are `name` and `value`. You could map the `NamedNodeMap` to a plain object keyed by those properties, each having the corresponding value.

You can use the second argument of `Array.from` for such kind of mapping and join the results into a single object with `Object.assign`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = Object.assign({},
            ...Array.from(target.attributes, ({name, value}) => ({[name]: value}))
        );

    console.log(text);

}, false);
```

```css
div.some_class:nth-child(1) {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div.some_class:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='some_class' id="some_id"></div>
<div class='some_class' data-attribute="some_data"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was debugging elements with cluttered attributes, I wanted a simple way to clean them up and came across [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes), which led to [NamedNodeMaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap), and finally DDG led me here.

After a bit of testing, I ended up with (using the OP's terms, and splitting a one-liner in 3 to better illustrate the process)**:**

**Code**

```
myObjArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.attributes)
myStrArr = myObjArr.map(function(item){return item.name+'='+item.value})
text = JSON.stringify(myStrArr)
```

---

> myObjArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.attributes)

Line 1 converts the NamedNodeMaps object (target.attributes) into an array using the normal HTML collection .slice() approach, in general**:**

namedNodeMap elems ==> array obj elems, e.g.**:**
      { "0"**:**{ name**:**value }, ... } ==>  [ { name**:**value }, ... ]

At this stage, each array element can still be referenced by index using the generic properties**:**

```
myObjArr[ index ].name
myObjArr[ index ].value
```

or the more general Object.keys method**:**

```
myObjArr[ Object.keys(myObjArr)[index] ]
```

---

> myStrArr = myObjArr.map(function(item){return item.name+'='+item.value})

Line 2 uses .map() to convert the array of objects into an array of strings, using the name/value properties noted above, so that**:**

[ { name**:**value }, ... ] ==> [ "name=value", ... ]

The .map() function can also be tweaked to return items as simple { name: value } objects, or [ name, value] arrays, etc., for example:

```
.map(function(aRow) { return {[aRow.name]:aRow.value} })    // as {name:value} objects

.map(function(aRow) { return [aRow.name, aRow.value] })     // as [name,value] arrays
```

---

And the third line just uses the old standby JSON.stringify to finish the conversion to a string, but .join() works just as well for simple arrays.

---

**Note:** If parsing or otherwise analyzing the string, any items containing an equal (=) or comma (,) may interfere, and must be taken into account in that case.